# what is spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC effect?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, application.properties

I just deploy my last spring boot api version with this update in the applciation.properties file

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

and after the users figured out that all their Date fields type have been changed with an +1h, and after i've checked the oracle database and figured out that the dates values changed also with an Hour added to the last value.

**Ex:**

Before the deployment:

```
validation_date = 30-JUN-20 10.00.00.000000000 AM
```

After the deployment:

```
validation_date = 30-JUN-20 11.00.00.000000000 AM
```

But All new created data after this deployment are inserted with a correct date values. so the problem happened just with the past data.

So have anyone an idea about this problem? just want to know if this property added to application.properties was the source of the problem or another thing.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.baeldung.com/mysql-jdbc-timezone-spring-boot

Comment: It gives an idea about what is it but I want to know the source of my problem, how the values of the dates changed? and if there is a way to reverse this property to the default value?